# Celery as a service - PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/run/celery'

Tags: python, linux, permissions, celery, systemd

I'm trying to create a service that runs `celery` but I came across permissions problem. I saw in many tutorials that pidfile path is `/var/run/celery/%n.pid` but it seems like my user doesn't have rights to write to `run`.

When I start the service, this is what it returns:

```
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/run/celery'
```

**celery.service**

```
[Unit]
Description=Celery Service
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=forking
User=master
Group=master
EnvironmentFile=/etc/conf.d/celery
WorkingDirectory=/home/master/myproject/
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi start ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'
ExecStop=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi stopwait ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE}'
ExecReload=/bin/sh -c '${CELERY_BIN} multi restart ${CELERYD_NODES} \
  -A ${CELERY_APP} --pidfile=${CELERYD_PID_FILE} \
  --logfile=${CELERYD_LOG_FILE} --loglevel=${CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL} ${CELERYD_OPTS}'

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**celery.conf**

```
CELERYD_NODES="celery-worker"

CELERY_BIN="/home/master/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin/celery"

# App instance to use
CELERY_APP="myproject"


CELERYD_MULTI="multi"
# Extra command-line arguments to the worker
CELERYD_OPTS="--time-limit=300 --concurrency=3"

# %n will be replaced with the first part of the nodename.
CELERYD_LOG_FILE="/var/log/celery/%n%I.log"
CELERYD_PID_FILE="/var/run/celery/%n.pid"
CELERYD_LOG_LEVEL="INFO"
```

How to make it work?

Comment: If you really want it in /var/run/celery then you should look into [tmpfiles.d](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/tmpfiles.d.html)

Comment: @DejanLekic I don't care about dir, what dir do you recommend?

Comment: It is IMHO easier to put Celery in /opt/celery and PID and log file there too. Make it be owned by "celery" user/group as well.

Answer (score 8):

Dont know if it is the best approach, but here is how i solved mine...

```
$sudo mkdir /var/run/celery
```

user and group don't necessarily have to be celery..

```
$sudo chown -R celery:celery /var/run/celery
```

```
$sudo chmod o+w /var/run/celery
```

and then

```
$sudo service celery restart
```

Comment: Did the job. Thanks @goodnews john

Answer (score 5):

Add the parameter `RuntimeDirectory=celery` to the `celery.service` file
The command RuntimeDirectory automatically creates a directory in /var/run/

Comment: Hello, please don't just submit code in your answer(s), add some details as to why you think this is the optimal solution.

Comment: This is the best solution since `RuntimeDirectory` is automatically created / deleted at start / stop of service.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of [goodnews john](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14432913/goodnews-john) works, but the folder `/var/run/` will be cleared on reboot.

To make it persistent, you can add a file in `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/`, for example `/usr/lib/tmpfiles.d/celery.conf`.

Write this into the file:
`d /var/run/celery 0755 <your_user> <your_group>`

Answer (score 1):

I saw the same problem, and it turned out that I created `/var/log/celery` and `/var/run/celery` with root privilege, it looked like this

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 6 Aug  4 09:40 /var/log/celery
```

but I specified in `/etc/default/celeryd` my celeryd worker run as some non-root user, assume `me`, so `me` has no write/execute permission to `/var/log/celery`, so it got permission denied.

You may either create your `/var/log/celery` directory under user `master` group `master` or grant write/execute to user `master` (simply run `chmod o+w /var/log/celery` may be insecure, though I did in testing and hopefully it worked.